# iOS - Smaller buttons within one large button

Tags: ios

I want to have one large button on the screen that performs an action when single-tapped. I also want there to be 6 buttons within the large button that perform different actions when double-tapped.

I am thinking of making the large button a simple UIView, adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to it, and then adding the 6 buttons within that view with UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat and checking if tapCount == 2. Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the `[UIView handleTouches:]` method. You can use it to determine which view handles the touch based on the tapCount, instead of having to figure out which button the user tapped from the position within the superview